# ionic 2 can't use and display video with ionic-native (cordova plugin) videoplayer

Tags: cordova, android-studio, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

In my [ionic 2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/) project I have to play video from youtube/video/daylymotion **url** (So I need a videoplayer, not the native [youtube video player](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/youtubevideoplayer/)). I am on linux elementary os (based on **ubuntu 16.04**).

I use the native **videoplayer** plugin [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/videoplayer/).

So this is how I have proceeded to import the plugin:

1. **I run the command in my terminal**

   `ionic plugin add https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer`

Note that if I follow the plugin github [page](https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer) I have this error **`Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com.moust.cordova.videoplayer`** in the terminal outpout if I run the command: `cordova plugin add com.moust.cordova.videoplayer`

2. I add the additionnal codes in my different files.

I have in a view a list-item with `<ion-card>` tag all the urls I recover from a json file. This is the code of the view named `video-list.html`:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let video of videosService.videos">
    <ion-card-content>
      <button (click)="openVideoPage($event, video.url)">
        <ion-icon name="play"> click here to play the video !</ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Then in my video-list.ts I do this:

```
openVideoPage(event, urlNavParameter){
    this.navCtrl.push(VideoPlayerPage, {urlNavParameter}); 
    // to recover the right url later in the separate view
  }
```

Note here that I open a new page to display the video, in a view named `play-video.html`. This is the content:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>videoPlayer</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

Then in my `play-video.ts` I have this code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { VideoPlayer } from 'ionic-native'; // to import video player
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'; // to prevent from xss


@Component({
  selector: 'page-play-video',
  templateUrl: 'play-video.html'
})
export class VideoPlayerPage {

  public url: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.domSanitizer = domSanitizer;
    this.url = domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.navParams.get("urlNavParameter"));
  }

  displayVideo(url) {
    VideoPlayer.play(url).then(() => {
     console.log('video is displaying');
    }).catch(err => {
     console.log(err); 
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log(this.url);
    this.displayVideo(this.url);
  }
}
```

I have no errors with my code itself, but the videoplayer does not appears and none of my videos are displayed and played by a video player in my view.

I launch the application in my browser, I have this error in the console browser:

[image]

I understand that I have to emulate the android device. So I installed java jdk and android studio.
Everything works well, except the view with the video player, where I have no video displayed in in a video player (same problem).

[image]

Have I miss something in my code, my view ?

This is the output of my terminal when I launch the command `ionic emulate -l -c -s android`:

[image]

Of course `codova.js` is in y `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>
  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>
  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just for more information, this is the outpout of `ionic info` command:

```
Your system information:
Cordova CLI: 4.2.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: there is no `this.navParameter` declared either..is this a typo?

Comment: @suraj yes indeed, I have incorrectly pasted the code. Sorry. I fix this and this is how my code looks like for now.

Comment: did you try the solution?

Comment: try `ionic run android` instead of emulate

Comment: do you have `  <script src="cordova.js"></script>` in index.html?

Comment: try to call inside `platform.ready().then(()=>{})`

Comment: @suraj see my edit I paste my `index.html`. And cordova.js is imported in this file. When you suggest me to make the call `platform.ready().then(()=>{})`, I have to make it in the file `play-video.ts` ?

Comment: cordova plugin calls should be made after platform is ready..otherwise it wont get the global object.. not really sure if that is the cause of your error

Comment: @suraj I implemented the platform component from ionic-native, like you suggested me, but indeed, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Your cordova version seems old.. try updating it and then running..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134968/discussion-between-suraj-and-french-dev).

Comment: `npm install -g cordova@latest`